# Mule ESB: implement both Basic And Database based Spring Security Authentication

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, mule

I am trying to implement both Basic and Database(jdbc-data-source) based authentication in my Mule application using Spring-Security framework.

Below is my code for Basic Authentication:

```
    <mule-ss:security-manager>
    <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
</mule-ss:security-manager>
<spring:beans>
    <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <ss:authentication-provider>
            <ss:user-service id="userService">
                <ss:user name="${basic.username}" password="${basic.password}" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </ss:user-service>
        </ss:authentication-provider>
    </ss:authentication-manager>
</spring:beans>
<flow name="BasicAuthenticationFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener" path="basicauth" doc:name="HTTP"/>
     <logger message="Request received ...!!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Request Logger"/>
    <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
    <set-payload value="You are logged in !!!!!!"/>
```

the below code is for my Database based authentication:

```
 <ss:authentication-manager  alias="authenticationManager">
        <ss:authentication-provider>
       <ss:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="mssqlds" users-by-username-query="${db.users.by.username.query}"
              authorities-by-username-query="${db.authorities.by.username.query}" />
    </ss:authentication-provider>
  </ss:authentication-manager>
</spring:beans>
<mule-ss:security-manager>
      <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="jdbc-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager"/>
</mule-ss:security-manager>
```

when I run the application, the basic authentication is working fine, but Db based part is not working. to confirm the same, I commented the basic auth part and re-ran the application. then Database based auth is working fine. Can i get any inputs on implementing both authentications without disturbing the functionality of other?